# Cannot set property 'onsubmit' of null in laravel when redirecting shows blank page

Tags: javascript, laravel

Cannot set property 'onsubmit' of null in laravel when redirecting shows blank page
my code

```
<body>
    <section id="container" class="">
      @if (Auth::guard('admin')->check())
          @include('admin.header.header')
          @include('admin.sidebar.sidebar')
          @yield('content')
      @else
          @yield('content')
      @endif
    </section>

     <!-- javascripts -->
  {!!Html::script('js/jquery.js')!!}
  {!!Html::script('js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js')!!}
  ...........
  {!!Html::script('js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js')!!}

  </body>
```

my error

```
VM1673:277 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onsubmit' of null
    at <anonymous>:277:41
```

when i console it return null ,so the error is in this , what should i do

```
console.log(document.getElementById("subm"));
```

my script code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function waitForLoad(id, callback){
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        if(document.getElementById(id)){
            clearInterval(timer);
            callback();
        }
    }, 100);
}

waitForLoad("subm", function(){
    console.log("load successful, you can proceed!!");
    document.getElementById("subm").onclick = function()
    {
        alert("I got clicked");
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: Code works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/buLcyj1k/ Please create a [mre].

Comment: still not working ,showing same error

Comment: I didn't suggest a fix, because the code you posted *works as expected*. Which means we cannot reproduce the issue, are therefore unable to help you and this question is in danger of getting closed.